# Having issues with php download

Tags: php, force-download

So I had this issue before but it was a PHP version issue. Now is not the case.

Never changed the code, and it was working fine. Changed hosting only but i dont think that should have an issue.

The only thing i get is garbage code.

link to download is like this: https://example.com/forum/download.php?file=TEST.zip

```
<?php

$file = 'TEST.zip';
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    while (ob_get_level()) {
        ob_end_clean();
    }
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: what is `garbage code.` mean.  And I don't think the question should look like it does, just saying block comment is `<` in SO,  Block code is 4 leading spaces.

Comment: I'm new here, if you just able to help me that would help.

Comment: Well the first thing I would do is move `readfile` and `exit` after the loop, you don't really want them in the loop.  It could cause a bad file if `ob_get_level() > 1`

Comment: Actually it is outside of the loop, that is why formatting matters.  But the next thing I would do is remove this piece of junk `?>`

Answer (score 0):

The best I can figure with the limited code posed is this remove this thing `?>`  I hate this tag, I never use it personally.

It's not needed if there is nothing after the PHP like HTML and it can actually corrupt your file download if its like this

```
?>
//empty line here
```

Because of the way PHP works it will output anything outside of the TAGs as content, so anything before or after them could wind up in your file depending where the call and such happen.

I guess the `exit` would take care of that, but I don't like that tag. Because if you include a bunch of PHP files in you application, it only takes one file with a space outside of the tags to mess things up, and good luck finding that.

This bit

```
while (ob_get_level()) {
    ob_end_clean();
}
```

Clears the output buffer if it's set, which if this is all there is to your file it's probably not set.  Personally I would do it like this:

```
<?php  
 //start output buffering
 ob_start();

//be careful with casing
// - Windows is case insensitive
// - Linux is case sensitive
//for example if the file is named text.zip
//it will work on Windows, but be mission on Linux

$file = 'TEST.zip';

//without the file no download can happen
// -- so kill it before header are sent
// -- that way if file is missing we can easily debug it.
if (file_exists($file)) die("Missing required file {$file}");

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

$debug = '';
while (ob_get_level()) {
    //end all output buffering before file download
    //save this stuff, there could be useful debug information in here.
    $debug .= ob_get_clean();
}

if(!empty($debug)){
    //put "stuff" in a file 
    // -- FILE_APPEND = append to end of log
    // -- lock writing on the file for this opperation
    // --- its possible 2 clients could download the same time.
    file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/download_error.txt', $debug, FILE_APPEND|FILE_EX);
}

//finally output the file
readfile($file);
//this is good
exit;
```

This way you can record the output without messing up the download.  Basically you are throwing that stuff away, and it could be useful information.

Other then that everything else looks ok, I mean there is not much to it that could go wrong.  If I knew what `garbage code.` was maybe I could help more.  Maybe the original file is no good, who knows...

I cant say with any certainty any of this will fix your problem, most of what I put is just my personal preference on logging and order of execution.  But it probably wont fix it.

**SECURITY**

As a final note I should mention you should be very careful with this `?file=TEST.zip`  A malicious user can do this.

```
 ?file=../../../../etc/passwd  //which is a bad example (unless PHP is admin)
```

Basically they can use your input to transverse the directory structure.  A better way would be to do it like this

```
 $file = false;
 switch($_GET['file']){
      case 'TEST.zip': //you can even use a hash 
          $file = 'TEST.zip';
      break;

      //you can even use a hash instead of the name
      //this prevents errors caused by things like quotes in the filename.
      //something as simple as switch(md5($_GET['file'])), is finr
      case 'uiOzAWe8aser':
          //then the user has no access to your filesystem
         $file = 'TEST.zip';
      break;
      default: die('File not found '.$_GET['file'];
 }
```

Of course this may not be practical in many cases, but you can verify it in a DB, etc.